# Rebuild a list from a section of div elements via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML section of divs which I would like to transform into a list item.

Here is an snippet example of the HTML:

```html
<div>
  <small>2019-10-31 10:41 Customer unregistered</small>
</div>
<div>
  <small>2019-08-31 10:41 Customer investigated</small>
</div>
<div>
  <small>Comment:</small>
</div>
<div>
  <small>- payment issue</small>
</div>
<div>
  <small>2019-08-31 10:41 Customer registered</small>
</div>
```

Ultimately I would like it to be a NESTED unordered list i.e.

```html
<ul>
  <li>2019-10-31 10:41 Customer unregistered</li>
  <li>2019-08-31 10:41 Customer investigated
    <ul>
      <li>Comment:</li>
      <li>- payment issue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2019-08-31 10:41 Customer registered</li>
</ul>
```

Note that "main" list entries can be identified with the start of a date and time. "sub" lists and their entries are those that do not start with a date and time.

Is their anyone who knows if this abracadabra is possible somehow via jQuery when the document is loaded?

I understand that I can identify a "main" list item by the first 16 characters (which should represent a date-time object) so I can try they match a regular expression:

```
var check = isDate('2018-08-01 18:30');
alert(check)

var check = isDate('hungry like a wolf');
alert(check)

function isDate(_date){
        const _regExp  = new RegExp('^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])?$');
        return _regExp.test(_date);
    }
```

A liten progress update:

I now can scan the main list items based upon the first 16 characters and see if they match the regular expression. then I can alter the elements. I haven't come so far with nested lists yet:

```
function isDate(_date){
    const _regExp  = new RegExp('^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])?$');
    return _regExp.test(_date);
}

$(function() {    
    $("div.histEntry").each(function( index, value ) {
      if(isDate($(value).text().trim().substring(0, 16))){
           var element = $(this);
           element.replaceWith('<li><p><small>' + element.text() + '</small></p></li>');
      }else{
           var element = $(this);
           element.replaceWith('<div><p><small>' + element.text() + '</small></p></div>');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. What have you researched or tried? But certainly it would be simpler and more efficient to change the code which generates this HTML in the first place, if that's an option

Comment: @ADyson I am more a back-end guy so front-end is more problematic for me, ofcourse I will update my question as further I come with solving the puzzle as I just did

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery MAP](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) plus [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

I did not see your ULs were nested until I edited your question for clarity.

This code will give you the text you want to work on in an array

```
$("div small")
  .map((i, el) => $(el).text()) // jQuery.map
  .get()
```

My first attempt did not nest

```js
const $container = $("#container");
$container.html(() =>
  $("<ul/>").html(() =>
    $("div small",$container)
    .map((i, el) => $(el).text()) // jQuery.map
    .get() // text array
    .map(el => `<li>${el}</li>`) // Array.map
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <small>2019-10-31 10:41 Customer unregistered</small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>2019-08-31 10:41 Customer investigated</small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>Comment:</small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>- payment issue</small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>2019-08-31 10:41 Customer registered</small>
  </div>
</div>
```